# Kotlin alternative for @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")

Tags: kotlin, annotations, suppress-warnings

Is there alternative for `@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")` in kotlin?
I've tried `@Suppress("WeakerAccess")` but no luck. It's pretty annoying to see "*Function xxx could be private*" when developing a library.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")`.

Comment: It's working, thank you Notably, `@Suppress("WeakerAccess")` does not work for Kotlin.

Answer (score -1):

Write test code in `src/test/kotlin` that makes use of your functions.

Comment: It is quite universal but boring method. So as I understand there is no kotlin alternative.